# Count elements in a list against a list of possible values

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a list as follow:

```
a = [50, 75, 75, 100, 50, 50, 75, 50, 75]
```

where possible values are: 0,25,50,75 and 100

from there I want to group the values in a dictionary as:

```
result= {'0':0,'25':0,'50':4,'75':4,'100':1}
```

I have tried with collections:

```
import collections
a = [50, 75, 75, 100, 50, 50, 75, 50, 75]
counter=collections.Counter(a)
```

But the result:

```
Counter({50: 4, 75: 4, 100: 1})
```

does not account for: '0':0,'25':0

How can I pass the list of option to this or another function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an empty dictionary with default values of `0` using `dict.fromkeys()` and then merge that with the `Counter()` output:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [50, 75, 75, 100, 50, 50, 75, 50, 75]
possible =[0,25,50,75, 100]

{**dict.fromkeys(possible, 0), **Counter(a)}
# {0: 0, 25: 0, 50: 4, 75: 4, 100: 1}
```

or

```
d = dict.fromkeys(possible, 0)
d.update(Counter(a))
```

Comment: what does the "**" stands for?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez that is dictionary unpacking. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/ It's available in 3.5 or greater (I *think*).

Answer (score 4):

For my proposed solution you need to define a list (or some other kind of iterable) that holds all the possible keys (in your case: integers).

The you could build a new `dict`, assigning the value `0` for the keys that you don't find inside the `counter`. Here we can use a nice little property of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that says (thanks @MykolaZotko for pointing that out):

> `Counter` objects have a dictionary interface except that they return a zero count for missing items instead of raising a `KeyError`.

So the code could be:

```
import collections
possible_keys = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]

data = [50, 75, 75, 100, 50, 50, 75, 50, 75]
counter = collections.Counter(data)
```

We can create a new `dict` with zeros for missing elements:

```
dict_with_zeros = {
    k: counter[k]
    for k in possible_keys}
```

Or if you just need to print the counter without actually creating a new `dict` with the zeros:

```
for k in possible_keys:
    print(k, counter[k])
```

Comment: Try `{k: counter[k] for k in possible_keys}`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dictionary with those values using no additional imports like this:

```
a = [50, 75, 75, 100, 50, 50, 75, 50, 75]
required = [0,25,50,75,100]

result = {item:a.count(item) for item in required}
```

This is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/); it creates all keys present in `required` and counts their occurrences, if any, in `a`. `result` will contain

```
{0: 0, 25: 0, 50: 4, 75: 4, 100: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using just `dict`-comprehension following way:

```
a = [50, 75, 75, 100, 50, 50, 75, 50, 75]
possible = [0,25,50,75,100]
result = {p:0 for p in possible}
for i in a:
    result[i] += 1
print(result)  # {0: 0, 25: 0, 50: 4, 75: 4, 100: 1}
```